# RoR: Different user roles for each new created record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I want to make a record management system.  The system will have 4 different user roles: `Admin`, `Viewer`, `Editor` and `Reviewer`.

While the first two are easy to implement using gems such as **cancan** and **declarative authorization**, the other two are not so simple.

Basically each new record is created by an `Admin` (only an Admin can create new records), and should have its own separate `Editor` and `Reviewer` roles.  That is, a user can be assigned many different roles on different records but not others, so a user might be assigned `Editor` roles for Record A and C but not B etc.

- Editor: can make changes to the record, and will have access to specific methods in the controller such as edit etc.
- Reviewer: will be able to review (view the changes) made to the record and either approve it or submit comments and reject.
- Viewer: Can only view the most recent approved version of each record.

Are there any ways of handling such record-specific user roles?

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished without too much effort with the cancan gem and a block condition.  A block condition checks for authorization against an instance.  Assuming your Record class had an editors method that returns an array of authorized editors the cancan ability for updating a Record might look something like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    ...

    can :update, Record do |record|
      record.editors.include?(user)
    end

    ...    

  end
end
```

See "Block Conditions" on the CanCan wiki:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

**Update**

Storing which users have which access to which records could be done many ways depending on your specific needs.  One way might be to create a model like this to store role assignments:

```
class UserRecordRoles < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has three fields:  role, user_id, record_id
  attr_accessible :role, :user_id, :record_id
  belongs_to :user_id
  belongs_to :record_id
end
```

Now create a has_many association in the User and Record models so that all role assignments can be easily queried.  An editors method might look like this:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :user_record_roles

  def editors
    # This is rather messy and requires lot's of DB calls...
    user_record_roles.where(:role => 'editor').collect {|a| a.user}
    # This would be a single DB call but I'm not sure this would work.  Maybe someone else can chime in?  Would look cleaner with a scope probably.
    User.joins(:user_record_roles).where('user_record_roles.role = ?' => 'editor')
  end

  ...

end
```

Of course there are many many ways to do this and it varies wildly depending on your needs.  The idea is that CanCan can talk to your model when determining authorization which means any logic you can dream up can be represented.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a couple of questions, how would you create the new Roles for the record when its created and how do you then assign them roles to a user? what I'm asking is how would the editors method work?

Comment: @Mo that got a bit more complicated but I hope it's clear enough.  Actually storing the roles is very application-specific.  Whatever makes sense for your project is the way to go.  Once you figure out what makes the most sense for your application then tell CanCan how your application works and sprinkle those `can?` methods over your application.  I would be very interested if someone could make my `editors` method better!  It smells bad to me.

Comment: @MDabus I was thinking of making a Roles table which will have a many to many relationship with User's. then when a new Record is created the system can create 2 new Roles in the role table (Role objects created will take the Record's ID). then in the user edit page, users can be assigned roles. the editors method can loop through all the users that belong to that records role and add them to an array? this is all theoretical, would you say it would work?

Comment: @Mo That sounds doable in theory.  If a role assignment is related to a role, a user, and a record then I would make sure those relationships are reflected in your models with has_many, has_many :through, and belongs_to associations.  Then you would use an editors scope instead of writing an editors method by hand.  There really isn't any reason to manually loop through users to build your own array if your associations accurately reflect the "real world" business model.